# Cloud server running slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, io, find

Can anyone help with this:

One of our cloud servers is running slow and after running `iotop` I've noticed the below command running for nearly 2 hours, but I'm the only one who would run commands on this server. I haven't and there has been no breach.

```
find / -ignore_readdir_race ( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs ~var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\) ) -prune -o -print0
```

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: This is a find command with syntax issues. Somebody trying to retrieve a directory listing. Try a `man find` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to previous answer check that you're using appropriate instance type. Read more documentation about instance type with burstable performance:

> For example, a t2.small instance receives credits continuously at a
>   rate of 12 CPU Credits per hour. This capability provides baseline
>   performance equivalent to 20% of a CPU core. If at any moment the
>   instance does not need the credits it receives, it stores them in its
>   CPU Credit balance for up to 24 hours. If and when your t2.small needs
>   to burst to more than 20% of a core, it draws from its CPU Credit
>   balance to handle this surge seamlessly. Over time, if you find your
>   workload needs more CPU Credits than you have, or your instance does
>   not maintain a positive CPU Credit balance, we recommend either a
>   larger T2 size, such as the t2.medium, or a Fixed Performance Instance
>   type.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/